# node npm- install not working

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

Both npm install global and installing as a project dependency are not working. After entering a command the  little rotating pipe (Windows) that signifies that download has started keeps going on forever. All the other cli like bower and jspm are downloading the dependencies just fine. Anyone have a solution to what might be going on.

Update: I tried using --verbose flag but It gets stuck at the request to get the package from the registry

```
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-prebuilt
```

Which had me wondering if the registry is down or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I installed nodejs with the msi 64bit installer.
Then I checked that  the path was correctly updated:
In you path system you must have : {rest of your path..;}C:\Users{YourUserProfile}\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs

I has to be the path to npm before nodejs.
Then I tried the command : `npm install underscore` and still nothing but the rotating pipe.
After searching, you must delete the TEMP variable situated at the same place as the Path variable (check this [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7318)). Only after this, npm worked, and I could use `npm install` finally.

Hope it can help.